You do not have permission to create an audience on one or more event sources
I have two function. One is responsible for creating audience for the engaged page of Facebook and the other is for creating a custom audience for Instagram business account. I am using step functions to call my lambdas function. But whenever I try to create audience of Facebook and Instagram simultaneously, so I received an error of permission

No permission on event source: You do not have permission to create an audience on one or more event sources

But when I try to create a single audience for example just only for Facebook or just only for Instagram there is no error for the permissions but when I try to create audience simultaneously for the Facebook and for the Instagram business account I got this error
const createSocialAudience = async ({
    name,
    pageId,
    adsAccountId,
  } ) => {
    if (!name || !adsAccountId || !pageId) {
      throw new Error('Marketing API call missing required params');
    }

    const requestData = {
      name,
      description: 'Recent page visitors (from 360 days) visiting given page',
      rule: {
        inclusions: {
          operator: 'or',
          rules: [
            {
              event_sources: [
                {
                  type: "page",
                  id: pageId,
                },
              ],
              retention_seconds: 60* 60* 24 * 360,
              filter: {
                operator: 'and',
                filters: [
                  {
                    field: 'event',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: 'page_engaged',
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      access_token: params.marketingApiToken,
    };

    const { data } = await httpClient.post(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_${adsAccountId}/customaudiences`,
      JSON.stringify(requestData)
    );

    return data;
  };

  const createInstagramAudience = async ({
    name,
    igUserId,
    adsAccountId,
  })  => {
    if (!name || !adsAccountId || !igUserId) {
      throw new Error('Marketing API call missing required params');
    }

    const requestData = {
      name,
      description: 'Recent page visitors (from 360 days) visiting given page',
      rule: {
        inclusions: {
          operator: 'or',
          rules: [
            {
              event_sources: [
                {
                  type: 'ig_business',
                  id: igUserId,
                },
              ],
              retention_seconds: 60 *60 * 24 * 360,
              filter: {
                operator: 'and',
                filters: [
                  {
                    field: 'event',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: 'ig_business_profile_engaged',
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      access_token: params.marketingApiToken,


    };


    const { data } = await httpClient.post(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_${adsAccountId}/customaudiences`,
      JSON.stringify(requestData)
    );

    return data;
  };

Expecting to create both of my audience at the same time for example I want two type of
event_sources one for page of Facebook and one for ig_business
